# USB storage shareing over home/public Networks

Tags: networking, usb

Is it possible to put a USB storage device into a computer and then be able to see it on the whole network as a USB, similar to when you connect a printer to a computer and you're able to see it on the whole network as a public device?

If possible how can I do this and is there any open source software that will help with doing this? Also will the USB be read as a USB storage device or something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On any computer connected to your Wi-Fi network, launch a browser, and navigate to your router's IP address. You can find this on the back of the router, in the device manual, or by searching for it online. In most cases, it looks like `192.168.X.X`.

When the page loads, you'll be asked to log in with your username and password. If you changed it, you should know it. If you didn't, it's probably still admin (username), and admin (password).
Those who fall into the latter category, please change your password as soon as you can, and before proceeding to the next step.

Every router's interface is different, but if yours has a USB port, you'll find a link entitled something likeFile Sharing under the Administrator settings. In this window, enable the file sharing server (also called *SAMBA*). Apply the settings, and exit.

You're now ready to read and write to your attached hard drive. Open a file explorer window, and navigate to the Network folder in the left sidebar. Then, clear out the path at the top of the explorer window, and enter `\\[your IP address]`. So, for example, it might look like: `\\192.168.1.1`
With that, your drive will appear.

Open it to access its contents, just like any other folder. If you're asked to log in, simply use your router's login credentials (the same one used to log into the Web interface).

If you plan on leaving your hard drive attached, so that you can easily access it from any Explorer window. To do that, right-click the drive and select "*Map network drive...*" Give it a name, and the folder will appear in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no file systems that are designed for concurrent access by multiple drivers. Therefore, exposing a USB mass storage device as a block device to multiple computers at once can only lead to trouble (file or file system corruption or state inconsistency). To share the files on the device it is far better to use software designed for it (SMB/Samba, FTP, SFTP, NFS, ...).

However, if you know what you're doing (perhaps you want to use a file system that's not supported on the host), there's a tool called "network block device" (NBD). There's an [article in Linux magazine](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7118/) about it. You can configure it to serve your USB mass storage device node.

Failing that, you could try serving the device node using Samba/FTP/..., but I haven't tried this.

Comment: hmm... the NBD thing is kinda what im looking for, but it only works on linux, and i need it to work on windows, Thanks the help tho.